# python script to output data as csv and not JSON object

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a dataset like so:

```
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiMTA2MzEwMTkwIiwicyI6IkRvZnVlWGs1Unp5S2cyUlFOeWdXRmcifQ.v8u2XQwJUVflPipH2A_wg-HMrjYEl2BkL8EMOrRZ5m0,Back End Developer,n/a,Victoria,51.503378,-0.139134,United Kingdom,software development|sdlc|php|software design|compiler
```

I'm trying to append a `1` to each line, and for that I'm using the following python script:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("Y.csv", "rb"))
appendix = str('1')
for row in reader:
    row.append(appendix)
    print row
```

but I need the output to be in the form of a `.csv` document and this procedure outputs it in a JSON-eque format, like so:

```
['http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiMjY0OTM2Mzk3IiwicyI6IlR2dlB2cDZnU2RPajIxamF5R1BxbncifQ.xuWXv15319ifRV0LSShmSLZX0WxwH9kBW7e19osJZuM', '<strong>Analyst</strong>', 'Platinum Resources', 'Farringdon', '51.51985', '-0.11126', 'United Kingdom', 'leadership|finance|project management', '1']
```

how can I get the output to be in the style of `.csv`?

I tried some adaptation inspired by this:

```
import csv

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(a)
```

but it also didn't work, it ended up putting a `,` after every single character.

Comment: Where does a come from in writer.writerows(a)? I suspect it is a list of strings.

Comment: nowhere- it's just an example I used- I adapted it to something I could use but... it didn't work- so I deleted it- but I wanted to show you guys what I've tried so you don't think I'm some kind of lazy idiot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

DONE! answering my own questions!

```
with open('out.csv', 'r') as istr:
    with open('zhoutput.txt', 'w') as ostr:
        for line in istr:
            line = line.rstrip('\n') + ',1'
            print(line, file=ostr)
```